# setting a condition for a mixed list

Tags: python

Maybe there was a better way to do this, but I have a list of mixed elements:

```
outlist = [10, [ETSc, Juniper Hairstreak], [ETSc, Spotted Turtle],
           [ETSc, Blanding's Turtle], IWWH]
```

What I would like to do is iterate over this list and if the list element contains `ETSc`, then I want to convert it to a string like this:

```
ETSc (Juniper Hairstreak)
```

If it doesn't contain `ETSc` then I just want to convert it to a string:

```
IWWH
```

Ultimately the strings will populate a variable in an access database table.  But I have no idea how to tell Python to find the list elements containing `ETSc`, since some of the elements are lists within a list and some are just strings.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Please post code that will actually run.  You're missing some quotes in your example.  Also, "I have no idea" isn't helpful.  We don't know what's confusing you.  What did you actually try?  What didn't work?

Comment: ETSc, Juniper Hairstreak are string right? Don't forget using ""

Comment: In your sample code, none of the elements are strings, if you want them to be strings you have to put them between `''`: (Ex: `'ETSc'`)

Comment: you should accept one of the answers if any of them helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> input = [10, ["ETSc", "Juniper Hairstreak"], ["ETSc", "Spotted Turtle"], ["ETSc", "Blanding's Turtle"], "IWWH"]
>>> output = [elt[0] + " (" + elt[1] + ")" if type(elt) == list and elt[0] == "ETSc" else str(elt) for elt in input]
>>> output
['10', 'ETSc (Juniper Hairstreak)', 'ETSc (Spotted Turtle)', "ETSc (Blanding's Turtle)", 'IWWH']
```

---

As @julio commented, you could make this more readable using a function:

```
def xform(elt):
    if type(elt) == list and len(elt) > 1 and elt[0] == "ETSc":
        return elt[0] + " (" + elt[1] + ")"
    else:
        return str(elt)

output = [xform(elt) for elt in input]
```

Comment: In this case I would use a `def`, this `list comprehension` looks kinda messy

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!  This was very helpful!  I am still a bit of a beginner and had no clue how to reference an element of a list within a list.  Nor did I know about "type".  Many thanks to you both!!

Answer (score 0):

you could

```
import types

for e in outlist:
   if types.TypeList(e):
      e = str(e[0]+"("+e[1]+")")#or something like that
   else
      e= str(e)
```

good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
outlist = [10, ['ETSc', 'Juniper Hairstreak'], ['ETSc', 'Spotted Turtle'], ['ETSc', 'Blanding\'s Turtle'], 'IWWH']

["%s (%s)" % (x[0], x[1]) if type(x) == list else str(x) for x in outlist]
```